# Neutralino - Obfuscate resources file?

Tags: neutralinojs

Is there some way to Obfuscate the code that is inside the **resources.neu** file?
It can be read in any text editor... it contains the CSS HTML and JS content.
Not a big problem but can it be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .neu file is generated when you build your neutralino app, so you should obfuscate your source files first, and only then, build your neutralino app. The generated .neu file will contain the obfuscated code. To obfuscate your code there are a few solutions available, but Jscrambler seems to offer the most complete suite.

Answer (score 1):

As of January 2022 Neutralino Uses Electron's [Asar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asar) Format to bundle all the files together at one place which can be easily uncompressed using the same tool.

You can use code Bundlers like [ES Build](https://esbuild.github.io/) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) which will bundle and minify your Code and your bundled code is pretty much unreadable.

For Webpack there is a plugin [Webpack Obfuscator](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/webpack-obfuscator) which can be used to obfuscate your code even more.